# What does the settings "Insert // at the start of new lines when writing // comments" do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

The title.

[image]

It's in **Visual Studio > settings > text editor > c# > advanced > comments**.

(Hint: It does *not* add // when writing comments.)

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Text_Editor.CSharp.Advanced)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022#comments) also doesn't include any information about that option.

Comment: I'm noticing that checking/unchecking that option causes `Editor Help > Split string literals on enter` to be selected and deselected. I'm thinking that label in the UI got misapplied to the wrong data model property in the options editor, and you should file a bug with the Visual Studio team.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yeah, that's definitely a bug. It's doing the same for me as well.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: Yup, definitely looks like a half implemented feature. The config UI story was completed and the functionality part fell off the board. I've never done that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this feature is supposed to toggle is while editing a single-line comment, if you insert a newline in the middle, the next line (with remaining text) will continue the comment.  For example, inserting a newline at the | in `// foo|bar` becomes

```
// foo
// bar
```

Without this, it would be

```
// foo
bar
```

The Split String Literals option that @StriplingWarrior mentioned in the comments is similar but specific to strings. `"foo|bar"` becomes

```
"foo" +
"bar"
```

As for why the option doesn't do anything, StriplingWarrior was also spot on.  The code for this is in the Roslyn repository on GitHub, so:

- the option is [bound to the same setting storage](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/77c17746ec78a57ca0c84ef819614b82947fa94f/src/VisualStudio/CSharp/Impl/Options/AdvancedOptionPageControl.xaml.cs#L118) as Split Strings
- the feature implementation [does use its own setting](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/77c17746ec78a57ca0c84ef819614b82947fa94f/src/EditorFeatures/Core/SplitComment/SplitCommentCommandHandler.cs#L77) (it's not meant to be shared)
- the setting [defaults to true](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/77c17746ec78a57ca0c84ef819614b82947fa94f/src/EditorFeatures/Core/SplitComment/SplitCommentOptions.cs#L17) if not set otherwise (so you'll always see that behavior), and per the above misbinding, there's no way to set it to false.

TL;DR: it's a handy feature, and there's a bug that you can't turn it off.

edit: issue opened [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/63309)